# control with url and my project files in php project

Tags: php, url

I am working on an e-commerce project , but i am facing two problems.

first, when i click on sub category link such as classic shoes
supposed that  mysite.com/classic-shoes.php open
now i need to make classic-shoes.php file and file to every sub category and that is nonsense

second, i want my url to be like that
https://www.jumia.com.eg/mobiles-tablets/

not having .php in the end of the link..
forgive me on my bad english but i hope that you understand my problem, thanks in advance

Comment: do you have htaccess enabled!

Comment: idk i work with localhost

Comment: you are using apache server?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the php extension from url you can use htaccess file to rewrite the rule

1. create `.htaccess` file in root directory of your project — use sublime text or any other text editor to create if you are unable to create .`htaccess` file.
2. put the rule below in this file.

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]+)$ $1.php [L]
   ```

For more reference:

- http://www.htaccess-guide.com/
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @abshishek 
thank you alot , its work ..but what about the other problem ?

Comment: what other problem i didn't get.

Comment: when i click on classic shoes sub category for example ,, supposed that ecommerce/classic-shoes will open ,, but the problem that i have many of sub category , i must do file for every sub category in my project ?

Comment: you can use above logic for every php file for which you want to remove extension and please edit your question with example for more understanding.